# Opening new link in new tab

Tags: javascript, tabs

> Hi I am working on j2ee web application. But I am facing one problem
>   when I am trying to open clicked new link in new tab. As if it is
>   opening new tab but it is appending url link over my web application
>   root context path.
>
> My web page where I am clicking.

[image]

> And the error page shown below,

[image]

> As you can see I am able to open new tab but problem is it link is
>   appended with root path shown by yellow color.
>
> I tried this by this code,

```
window.open("www.yahoo.com", "_blank");
```

> also tried using,

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you don't specify `http://` the standard is to take the path of your site in this case `localhost:8080`..
try this:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

or this:

```
window.open("http://www.yahoo.com", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 2):

if you do not specify a protocol then it is assumed to be a local address (*local to your website*)

So use `http://` at the start..

Answer (score 0):

```
target="_blank"
```

This is the code to say the link should be opened in a blank page.